# Juniversal Translator Error: The import org.junit cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, macos, junit, code-translation

I Am using Juniversal to Translate Java To Objective-C And C#

Also JUnit added to Android project (jar file , gradle)

when i use Mac OSX (Yosemite) terminal to Run command :

```
java -jar juniversal/juniversal-translator/build/libs/juniversal-translator-0.8.3.jar -o $OBJC_OUTPUT -l c# -classpath  jsimple/libraries/jsimple-util/build/libs/jsimple-util-0.9.3.jar  -sourcepath $HOME/androidstudioprojects/testbuild/app/src/main/java  $HOME/androidstudioprojects/testbuild/app/src/test/java
```

it shows error :

```
    /Users/emaar/AndroidStudioProjects/TestBuild/app/src/test/java
    Error: The import org.junit cannot be resolved
    File /Users/emaar/AndroidStudioProjects/TestBuild/app/src/test/java/com/emaar/app/testbuild/ExampleUnitTest.java
    3:7:  import org.junit.Test;
    ^
    Error: The import org.junit cannot be resolved
    File /Users/emaar/AndroidStudioProjects/TestBuild/app/src/test/java/com/emaar/app/testbuild/ExampleUnitTest.java
    5:14:  import static org.junit.Assert.*;
    ^
    Error: Test cannot be resolved to a type
    File /Users/emaar/AndroidStudioProjects/TestBuild/app/src/test/java/com/emaar/app/testbuild/ExampleUnitTest.java
    11:5:      @Test
    ^
    Error: The method assertEquals(int, int) is undefined for the type ExampleUnitTest
    File /Users/emaar/AndroidStudioProjects/TestBuild/app/src/test/java/com/emaar/app/testbuild/ExampleUnitTest.java
    13:8:          assertEquals(4, 2 + 2);
    ^
    Translating /Users/emaar/AndroidStudioProjects/TestBuild/app/src/test/java/com/emaar/app/testbuild/ExampleUnitTest.java
    org.juniversal.translator.core.JUniversalException: null
    Error occurred with context at position
    File /Users/emaar/AndroidStudioProjects/TestBuild/app/src/test/java/com/emaar/app/testbuild/ExampleUnitTest.java
    13:8:          assertEquals(4, 2 + 2);
    ^
    at org.juniversal.translator.core.SourceFileWriter.writeRootNode(SourceFileWriter.java:120)
    at org.juniversal.translator.csharp.CSharpTranslator.translateFile(CSharpTranslator.java:60)
    at org.juniversal.translator.core.Translator$1.acceptAST(Translator.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnitResolver.resolve(CompilationUnitResolver.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnitResolver.resolve(CompilationUnitResolver.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.createASTs(ASTParser.java:990)
    at org.juniversal.translator.core.Translator.translate(Translator.java:247)
    at org.juniversal.translator.core.Translator.translate(Translator.java:87)
    at org.juniversal.translator.core.Translator.main(Translator.java:50)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.juniversal.translator.csharp.MethodInvocationWriterBase.writeMethodInvocation(MethodInvocationWriterBase.java:50)
    at org.juniversal.translator.csharp.MethodInvocationWriter.write(MethodInvocationWriter.java:33)
    at org.juniversal.translator.csharp.MethodInvocationWriter.write(MethodInvocationWriter.java:27)
    at org.juniversal.translator.core.SourceFileWriter.writeNode(SourceFileWriter.java:98)
    at org.juniversal.translator.core.ASTNodeWriter.writeNode(ASTNodeWriter.java:42)
    at org.juniversal.translator.csharp.CSharpSourceFileWriter$11.write(CSharpSourceFileWriter.java:304)
    at org.juniversal.translator.csharp.CSharpSourceFileWriter$11.write(CSharpSourceFileWriter.java:301)
    at org.juniversal.translator.core.SourceFileWriter.writeNode(SourceFileWriter.java:98)
    at org.juniversal.translator.core.ASTNodeWriter.writeNode(ASTNodeWriter.java:42)
    at org.juniversal.translator.csharp.MethodDeclarationWriter.lambda$writeBody$17(MethodDeclarationWriter.java:336)
    at org.juniversal.translator.csharp.MethodDeclarationWriter$$Lambda$10/146370526.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.juniversal.translator.core.ASTUtil.forEach(ASTUtil.java:530)
    at org.juniversal.translator.csharp.MethodDeclarationWriter.writeBody(MethodDeclarationWriter.java:327)
    at org.juniversal.translator.csharp.MethodDeclarationWriter.write(MethodDeclarationWriter.java:164)
    at org.juniversal.translator.csharp.MethodDeclarationWriter.write(MethodDeclarationWriter.java:35)
    at org.juniversal.translator.core.SourceFileWriter.writeNode(SourceFileWriter.java:98)
    at org.juniversal.translator.core.ASTNodeWriter.writeNode(ASTNodeWriter.java:42)
    at org.juniversal.translator.csharp.TypeDeclarationWriter.lambda$write$23(TypeDeclarationWriter.java:107)
    at org.juniversal.translator.csharp.TypeDeclarationWriter$$Lambda$3/518522822.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.juniversal.translator.core.ASTUtil.forEach(ASTUtil.java:520)
    at org.juniversal.translator.csharp.TypeDeclarationWriter.write(TypeDeclarationWriter.java:105)
    at org.juniversal.translator.csharp.TypeDeclarationWriter.write(TypeDeclarationWriter.java:32)
    at org.juniversal.translator.core.SourceFileWriter.writeNode(SourceFileWriter.java:98)
    at org.juniversal.translator.core.ASTNodeWriter.writeNode(ASTNodeWriter.java:42)
    at org.juniversal.translator.csharp.CompilationUnitWriter.writeNamespaceAndTypeDeclaration(CompilationUnitWriter.java:175)
    at org.juniversal.translator.csharp.CompilationUnitWriter.write(CompilationUnitWriter.java:54)
    at org.juniversal.translator.csharp.CompilationUnitWriter.write(CompilationUnitWriter.java:41)
    at org.juniversal.translator.core.SourceFileWriter.writeNode(SourceFileWriter.java:98)
    at org.juniversal.translator.core.SourceFileWriter.writeRootNode(SourceFileWriter.java:112)
    ... 8 more
```

How it could to be fix ?

Comment: Did you figure it out ?

Comment: it can not translate Java to Objective-C yet